# Connect with WiFi

Tags: android, networking, wifi

In my application I am showing list of available wifi network . I need to connect with a particular Wifi. My wifi network capabilities is WPA2.I have used below code to connect with that wifi .

```
  public void connectWiFi(ScanResult scanResult) {
    try {
        String networkSSID = scanResult.SSID;
        String networkPass = "**********";
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   
        conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        conf.priority = 40;
        if (scanResult.capabilities.toUpperCase().contains("WEP")) {
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
            conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

            if (networkPass.matches("^[0-9a-fA-F]+$")) {
                conf.wepKeys[0] = networkPass;
            } else {
                conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"".concat(networkPass).concat("\"");
            }

            conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;

        } else if (scanResult.capabilities.toUpperCase().contains("WPA")) {
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

            conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";

        } else {
            Log.v("rht", "Configuring OPEN network");
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        }

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        Log.v("rht", "Add result " + networkId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am always getting -1 as networkId. I have used right password. Please help.